# Getting COUNT from sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have:

```
res = db.engine.execute('select count(id) from sometable')
```

The returned object is `sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy`.

How do I get count value from `res`?

Res is not accessed by index but I have figured this out as:

```
count=None
for i in res:
    count = res[0]
    break
```

There must be an easier way right? What is it? I didn't discover it yet.
Note: The db is a `postgres` db.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While the other answers work, SQLAlchemy provides a shortcut for scalar queries as [`ResultProxy.scalar()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.scalar):

```
count = db.engine.execute('select count(id) from sometable').scalar()
```

`scalar()` fetches the first column of the first row and closes the result set, or returns None if no row is present. There's also [`Query.scalar()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.scalar), if using the Query API.

Comment: please note that if no rows are found, it'll return `None`

Answer (score 4):

what you are asking for called *unpacking*, `ResultProxy` is an [*iterable*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable), so we can do

```py
# there will be single record
record, = db.engine.execute('select count(id) from sometable')
# this record consist of single value
count, = record
```

Answer (score 3):

The `ResultProxy` in SQLAlchemy (as documented here http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html?highlight=execute#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy) is an iterable of the columns returned from the database. For a `count()` query, simply access the first element to get the column, and then another index to get the first element (and only) element of that column.

```
result = db.engine.execute('select count(id) from sometable')
count = result[0][0]
```

If you happened to be using the ORM of SQLAlchemy, I would suggest using the `Query.count()` method on the appropriate model as shown here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html?highlight=count#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.count

Comment: This syntax returns me this error `TypeError: 'ResultProxy' object is not subscriptable` with SQLAlchmy 1.3.20

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get count using sqlAlchemy core in fastapi:

```py
from sqlalchemy.future import select
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
...

query = select(func.count(Clients.id))
results = await db.execute(query)
data = results.scalars().first() # in my case return 2
```

- `Clients` is a model class represents `clients` table
- `db` is session : `Session = Depends(get_async_session)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do a count on a subquery, it is done in the following way:

```
from sqlalchemy import select, func

# Original query
query = select(user_table).where(user_table.c.name == "spongebob")

# Count query
count_query = select([func.count()]).select_from(query.alias("x"))

# Getting count
db.engine.execute(count_query).scalar()
```